# How can i update the same few indices in a matrix for every batch in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing

I want to create a lower triangular matrix for each batch in Tensorflow. I have two input tensors, one containing the diagonal terms, and one containing the off-diagonals. Dependent on the size of the required output, i have to fill in the lower triangular matrix for every batch.

Since you can't directly change values of tensors, I'm trying to update them. The issue seems to be related to index dimensions.

As an example, take a 3x3 matrix with a batch size of 10:

```
ld = tf.ones((10,3)) #Diagonal term
lo = tf.ones((10,3)) #Offdiagonal term
batch, N = ld.shape

L = tf.linalg.diag(ld) # Create diagonal matrix
idx = tf.constant(np.transpose(np.tril_indices(N,-1))) #Get the indices of offdiagonal terms
#Expanded indices to match batch dimensions
idx_exp = tf.expand_dims(idx, axis=0)
idx_exp = tf.tile(idx_exp, [batch, 1, 1])

# Update values
tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(L, idx, tf.reshape(lo,(batch,3,1)))
```

I'm not really sure how to get the 3d index matrix to work. I have tried using tile, but it gives errors that the dimensions are not correct. Anyone know how to do this?